# LUKS and LVM install: no boot (gave up waiting for root device)

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, lvm, luks

I just finished installing 12.04 on my system, configuring it with LUKS and LVM.

I can open the encrypted position just fine in a recovery disk, but I just can't seem to get it to boot.

It waits quite a while for the root partition, then explodes with errors on how it couldn't find the root device:

```
ALERT! /dev/mapper/vgcryptotop-lvcryptotoproot does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

I then get the initramfs prompt. I have tried running cryptsetup to open the disk from here, but it replies that cryptsetup isn't found by the shell.

I think that somehow, the OS was installed without LUKS and/or LVM. How do I fix this problem? How can I test my theory?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure dm-crypt.ko is in your initramfs. If it's NOT, it won't be able to mount the `/` filesystem and that's probably why you see the error.

`chroot` or just mount the `/boot` or `/` filesystem and do a `/sbin/lsinitramfs initrd.img-$(uname -r)`

You should see something like below (from a Debian wheezy box)

```
/boot# lsinitramfs initrd.img-`uname -r` | grep dm
...
lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/md/dm-crypt.ko
...
```

If it's NOT, you may have to chroot into the system from a live CD (e.g. system rescue cd) and regenerate initramfs -> `update-initramfs -u -k all`.

Boot and see if it helps, if all good, you should be prompt to input the passphrase for the encryption key.

Comment: I ran into the issue and your answer helped; thanks. I think what happened is that the first time I did ´update-initramfs´, it had a warning saying my crypttab was invalid, and I didn't notice the warning. As a result, ´dm-crypt.ko´ was not installed. Fixing my crypttab and running this command again fixed my situation.

Comment: If you're using a live Debian CD, `update-initramfs` is disabled. Use `/usr/sbin/update-initramfs.orig.initramfs-tools` instead.

Comment: [Instructions for getting to a chroot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_ChRoot). You may also need to install `lvm2` and `cryptsetup` in the live environment, and use them to gain access to your disks before chrooting.

Comment: This must be out of date for more recent ubuntu.  I'm missing dm-crypt.ko on the partition I'm trying to fix, but also on a working one.  I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04 - not the latest.